# How to convert a list of data frames to a big data frame with rownames from the list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to convert the following list of data frames

```
df1<-data.frame(a=1:4,b=5:8)
row.names(df1)<-paste("row",1:4,sep="")
df2<-data.frame(a=9:12,b=13:16)
row.names(df2)<-paste("row",5:8,sep="")
mylist<-list(df1,df2)

mylist

[[1]]
     a b
row1 1 5
row2 2 6
row3 3 7
row4 4 8

[[2]]
      a  b
row5  9 13
row6 10 14
row7 11 15
row8 12 16
```

to the following data frame

Desired output

```
  rnam.df1 a b  rnam.df2 c  d 
1 row1     1 5     row5  9  13
2 row2     2 6     row6  10 14
3 row3     3 7     row7  11 15
4 row4     4 8     row8  12 16
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns an output very similar to what you need:

```
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,FUN=function(x) cbind(rnam=row.names(x), x))
names(mylist2) <- paste('DF',1:length(mylist2),sep='')
d <- as.data.frame(mylist2)
row.names(d) <- 1:nrow(d)
```

Result:

```
  DF1.rnam DF1.a DF1.b DF2.rnam DF2.a DF2.b
1     row1     1     5     row5     9    13
2     row2     2     6     row6    10    14
3     row3     3     7     row7    11    15
4     row4     4     8     row8    12    16
```

Explanation:

- The first line simply adds a new column called `rnam` containing the
  `row.names` to each `data.frame` in the list. (and put this new column in the first position)
- the second line adds `DF1 ... DFn` names to the elements in the list
- calling `as.data.frame()`, the list is coerced to a `data.frame`, and all columns are prefixed with the name of the element in the list.
- finally, the last line removes the `row.names` inherited from the first data.frame of the list, by setting the row numbers

Comment: @digEmAll- Great- This is what I wish to have for the output. It is quite handy to have a "wide" format of df rather than "long" format. Many thanks

Comment: @Tony: just a note, this works **only** if the number of rows are the same for all the data.frame's. If you have different number of rows you should perform for example some sort of padding with NA's before calling these lines.

Comment: @digEmAll In first line you could use `lapply(mylist, function(x) cbind(rnam=row.names(x), x))`.

Comment: @Marek: yes that's better. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

`do.call(cbind, mylist)` gets you 99% of the way there. You might have to mung the column names a bit, depending on how stringent your requirements are.

Comment: @Ooi Thanks for your help - I am aware of this solution using do.call, but I need the specific format so I can output the data frame to a csv file format .

Answer (score 0):

pls try below code:

```
data.frame(cbind(rnam.df1=rownames(df1),a=df1$a),b=df1$b,rnam.df2=rownames(df2),c=df2$a,d=df2$b)
```

cbind() to combine these by columns ,return a list
rownames() to retrieve all row names from a data frame

Then , use data.frame to return a data frame object .

Comment: @zhang Thanks Shawn- What if my list of data frame is big? say 20. I was looking for something more general.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution:

```
n <- length(mylist)
z <- as.data.frame(c(lapply(mylist, rownames), mylist))
colnames(z) <- c(paste("rnam.df", 1:n, sep=""),
                 letters[1:(ncol(z)-n)])
rownames(z) <- NULL
z
#   rnam.df1 rnam.df2 a b  c  d
# 1     row1     row5 1 5  9 13
# 2     row2     row6 2 6 10 14
# 3     row3     row7 3 7 11 15
# 4     row4     row8 4 8 12 16
```